# Internal energy in an isochoric process

Tags: thermodynamics

Internal energy change in a reversible isochoric process can be expressed as $dU=C_VdT$. Can we also use it in an irreversible process or does it only work in reversible processes? Are $dU=C_VdT$ and $dU=TdS$ equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

For a reversible ideal gas process, yes your equations are correct and we can equate the two.

$$ dU = C_v dT $$

Also, $dU= TdS$, hence:

$$ TdS = C_v dT$$

$$ \Delta S =  C_v \ln T$$

We could also deduce the same from the state function for entropy,

$$ S = C_v \ln T + nR \ln V$$

Or,

$$ \Delta S = nC_v \Delta \ln T$$

> Can we also use it in an irreversible process?

Well you'd have trouble even defining the state variables if you are running an irreversible process. However, if after the irreversible process you let the gas equiliribiate then you can apply the above equations.

Answer (score 0):

> Are $dU=C_VdT$ and $dU=TdS$ equivalent?

Yes, it works for both a reversible or irreversible isochoric process.

The reason are (1) the change in internal energy and entropy between two states does not depend on the process(es) connecting the two states (reversible or irreversible) and (2) the change in entropy between states is *defined* for a reversible transfer of heat between the states, regardless of the process(es)
connecting the states. The difference between the reversible and irreversible process is the change in entropy for the latter is composed of two components: entropy change = entropy transfer + entropy generated. For the former it is only entropy change = entropy transfer.

In the case of an ideal gas, for any process, the specific internal energy is a function of temperature only according to

$$du=C_{V}dT$$

and since in this case the process is isochoric, $\delta w=0$ and from the first law

$$du=\delta q = C_{V}dT$$

Next, the change in specific entropy is the same between two states regardless of the process(es) connecting the states, reversible or irreversible. That change is *defined* for a reversible transfer of heat according to the following, but applies to any process, reversible or irreversible.

$$ds=\frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$$

From which we get

$$\delta q_{rev}=TdS$$

Combining the second and last equation, for a reversible or irreversible isochoric process we obtain

$$C_{V}dT=Tds=du$$

Hope this helps.